Help with Analytical Evaluation of $\int_0^{\infty}dt\, \frac{\text{e}^t\,t^4}{(1 - \text{e}^{t})^2}\frac{1}{t^2 + 4\pi^2}$
I recently came across the following integral
\begin{align}  
\int_0^{\infty}dt\, \frac{\text{e}^t\,t^4}{(1 - \text{e}^{t})^2}\frac{1}{t^2 + 4\pi^2}.
\end{align}
While I can evaluate it numerically without much difficulty, I would prefer an analytical approach. However, I have been unable to devise a suitable strategy to compute it in closed form.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or comments that could help me tackle this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Residue theorem should be your friend here.

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^4\text{e}^x}{(1 - \text{e}^{x})^2}\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2},dx$$
$$I(2\pi)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^4\text{e}^x}{(1 - \text{e}^{x})^2}\frac{1}{x^2 + 4\pi^2},dx$$
$$I(2\pi)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{x^2 + 4\pi^2}e^{-(n+1)x},dx$$
$$I(2\pi)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\int_0^{\infty}\sin(2\pi t)\int_0^\infty x^4 e^{-(n+1+t)x},dx,dt$$
$$I(2\pi)=\frac{12}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi t)}{(n+1+t)^5},dt=\cdots?$$
Where did you get this integral from?

Note that
$$I=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^4e^x}{\left(1-e^x\right)^2}\frac{1}{4\pi ^2+x^2}\:dx=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^4e^{-x}}{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^2}\frac{1}{4\pi ^2+x^2}\:dx.$$
Applying the geometric series yields
$$I=\int _0^{\infty }\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }ke^{-kx}\frac{x^4}{4\pi ^2+x^2}\:dx=\frac{1}{4}\int _0^{\infty }\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{x^4e^{-x}}{\pi ^2k^2+\frac{x^2}{4}}\:dx,$$
and since $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi k\right)^2+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}=4\zeta \left(2\right)\frac{\left(12-6x\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+x^2\right)}{x^4}$, we obtain
$$I=\zeta \left(2\right)\int _0^{\infty }e^{-x}\left(12-6x\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+x^2\right)\:dx.$$
By expanding and using that
$$\int _0^{\infty }e^{-x}\:dx=1,$$
$$\int _0^{\infty }x^2e^{-x}\:dx=2,$$
$$\int _0^{\infty }x\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{-x}\:dx=\int _0^{\infty }x\frac{e^{-x}+e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-x}}\:dx=\int _0^1\ln \left(x\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{1-x}\right)\:dx$$
$$=2\zeta \left(2\right)-1,$$
we arrive at
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^4e^x}{\left(1-e^x\right)^2}\frac{1}{4\pi ^2+x^2}\:dx=20\zeta \left(2\right)-30\zeta \left(4\right).$$
Equivalently,
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^4e^x}{\left(1-e^x\right)^2}\frac{1}{4\pi ^2+x^2}\:dx=\frac{10\pi ^2}{3}-\frac{\pi ^4}{3}.$$

Another possible (more complex) solution.
\begin{align}  
I=\int\frac{e^t}{(1 - e^t)^2}\frac{t^4}{t^2 + a^2}\,dt
\end{align}
Using
$$\frac{e^t}{\left(1-e^t\right)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \,e^{-n t}$$ and
$$\frac{t^4}{t^2 + a^2}=\frac{t^4}{(t-i a) (t+i a)}=t^2-a^2 +i\frac{ a^3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{t+i a}-\frac{1}{t-i a}\right)$$ Considering now
$$J_n=\int e^{-n t}\,\frac{t^4}{t^2 + a^2}\,dt$$ can be computed, after a few integrations by parts as
$$J_n=-\frac{e^{-n t} \left(n^2 t^2+2 n t+2-a^2 n^2\right)}{n^3}+$$
$$i\frac{ a^3}{2}\left(e^{i a n}\, \text{Ei}(-n(t+i a))-e^{-i a n}\, \text{Ei}(-n(t-i a)\right)$$
Using the bounds, $a=2\pi$, and the relation between the exponential integral function and the trigonometric integrals
$$K_n=n\,J_n=\frac 2{n^2}+4\pi^2(\pi  n (\pi -2 \,\text{Si}(2 n \pi))-1)$$
Asymptotically, the fact that
$$K_n=\frac{6}{\pi ^2 n^4}\Bigg(1-\frac{15}{2 \pi ^2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)  \Bigg)$$ predicts a rather fast convergence of the summation.
The problem is that, without cheating, I did not find what is  $0.428984325630180\cdots$. Asking inverse symbolic calculators gave the result (this is cheating).
